# How to remove some parts of line at freestyle line set?

Tags: rendering

I am learning to use freestyle lines to make hand painting lines and the result is very nice. [image]
So, is there any way to remove the eyes line?  I just want to keep the line outside the head.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select a variety of Edge Types to include in a 'Line Set' by checking 'Edge Type' and expanding its sub-panel. Hovering over the check boxes for a tool-tip gives a brief description of the characteristics defined by them; 'Contour' is "Outer Silhouette".

[image]

Don't forget Suzanne's eyes are mesh islands, so their edges are picked up by 'Border'.